# Can we combine a Markov chain and a Poisson process to construct a continuous Markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, poisson-process

If $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov chain, $N(t)$ is a poisson process. Can we say that $X_{N(t)}$ is a continuous Markov chain? How to prove that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See page 119 of [Essentials of Stochastic Processes](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/EOSP/EOSP2E.pdf), by Rick Durrett.